# Access Object.prototype.<method_name> method

Tags: javascript, zendesk, prototype-chain

I am working on a nodeJS based project where I am using `node-zendesk` package. This library provides functions to extract list of articles. But the method is in form of `Object.prototype.list`, I have no idea how to access this method.

`node-zendesk` package is inside `node_modules`.
The method I need to access is at `node-zendesk/lib/client/helpcenter/articles.js`

```js
var util = require('util'),
  Client = require('../client').Client



var Articles = exports.Articles = function(options) {
  this.jsonAPINames = ['articles', 'article'];

  this.sideLoadMap = [{
      field: 'author_id',
      name: 'user',
      dataset: 'users'
    },
    {
      field: 'section_id',
      name: 'section',
      dataset: 'sections'
    },
    {
      field: 'category_id',
      name: 'category',
      dataset: 'categories'
    }
  ];

  Client.call(this, options);
};

util.inherits(Articles, Client);

Articles.prototype.list = function(cb) {
  this.requestAll('GET', ['articles'], cb); //all
};
```

I need to access `Articles.prototype.list`. What I have tried is:

```js
var zendesk = require('node-zendesk');

var client = zendesk.createClient({
  username: < my_username > ,
  token: < my_token > ,
  remoteUri: < my_remoteUri > ,
  helpcenter: true
});

client.articles.list((err, req, result) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
    return;
  }
  console.log(JSON.stringify(result)); //gets the first page
});
```

The error is something like this:

```
{ Error: Zendesk Error (404): Item not found
> at checkRequestResponse (/<project_path>/node_modules/node-zendesk/lib/client/client.js:259:13)
    at requestCallback (/<project_path>/node_modules/node-zendesk/lib/client/client.js:274:3)
    at Request._callback (/<project_path>/node_modules/node-zendesk/lib/client/client.js:111:5)
    at Request.self.callback (/<project_path>/node_modules/request/request.js:185:22)
    at Request.emit (events.js:189:13)
    at Request.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:441:20)
    at Request.<anonymous> (/<project_path>/node_modules/request/request.js:1161:10)
    at Request.emit (events.js:189:13)
    at Request.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:441:20)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/<project_path>/node_modules/request/request.js:1083:12)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:277:13)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:194:15)
    at IncomingMessage.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:441:20)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1103:12)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
```

Help me to access `Articles.prototype.list` method.

Comment: Let me know if any additional information required

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're accessing the `articles`' list method correctly. You're probably just getting a network error due to the `404 Item Not Found`.

Comment: @KevalBhogayata I ran exactly the same code and got an error for the invalid remote URI. But in the debug stack there's `at exports.Articles.Articles.list (/home/jeangovil/node-zendesk/node_modules/node-zendesk/lib/client/helpcenter/articles.js:27:8)`. Which means It has invoked the Articles list.

Comment: yes, you are right, function is invoked. but I do not know, why I am not getting expected output (list of articles or something), and getting 404 instead ?